# How to looping correctly while inside while

Tags: php, while-loop

A little problem with my query, which my query is :

```
  SELECT * FROM tkursi WHERE tkursi.no_kursi NOT IN 
(SELECT no_kursi FROM tpesanantiket LEFT join tpenjadwalantiket ON 
tpenjadwalantiket.id_perjalanan=tpesanantiket.id_perjalanan LEFT JOIN tbus ON 
tbus.id_bus=tpenjadwalantiket.id_bus WHERE tbus.id_bus='$bus' AND 
tpesanantiket.id_perjalanan='$trip') ORDER BY no_kursi ASC
```

this query showing no_kursi where some number does not display which status ordered.

I want to change in list no_kursi there no_kursi which one status ordered still display but has comment ordered, other color background or can't click.

I try to use while inside while, but it not work properly.

```
<table class=" table table-bordered table-striped"> 
<?php
    $s = mysqli_query($koneksidb, "SELECT * FROM tkursi ORDER BY no_kursi ASC"); 
    while ($kolomData = mysqli_fetch_array($s)) { 
    $x = mysqli_query($koneksidb, "SELECT no_kursi FROM tpesanantiket 
    LEFT join tpenjadwalantiket ON tpenjadwalantiket.id_perjalanan=tpesanantiket.id_perjalanan
    LEFT JOIN tbus ON tbus.id_bus=tpenjadwalantiket.id_bus 
    WHERE tbus.id_bus='$Bus' AND tpesanantiket.id_perjalanan='$Trip'
GROUP BY no_kursi");
     while ($kolomx = mysqli_fetch_array($x)) { 
?>   
    <tr>   
<td width="200"> <input type="radio" name="tambah3" value="<?php echo $kolomData['no_kursi']; ?>"  
<?php echo ($data7==$kolomData['no_kursi']) ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>/>
<label  class="inline" for="<?php echo $kolomData['no_kursi']; ?>">
<?php echo $kolomData['no_kursi']; ?> &nbsp; 
<?php if ($kolomData['no_kursi']==$kolomx['no_kursi']) {
?> ordered 
<?php } ?>
</label> </td> 
    </tr>   
<?php  
} 
    }?>
```

the result has ordered in some no_kursi, but it loop too many.

**Edited** database show : 
$s : no_kursi 
001 
002 
003 
004 
005 
006 
007 
...  
043  
$x : no_kursi
005
006

the result  : 

 no_kursi 
001 
001 
002 
002 
003 
003 
004 
004 
005 ordered
005 
006 ordered 
006 
007 
007 
...  
043  
043

the result loop more as much as $x result.

Comment: It will be easy for others to understand if you add your database dump and expected output.

Comment: edited, hope it easy to understand. Thx for advise

Comment: I offer you not to use queries inside loops.

Comment: Then what's your expect output? Only the first loop?

Comment: @Mawia = yes, I expect like $s result but has ordered in the no_kursi in $x.

Comment: @Hilmi = How is it? can U show more advise?

Comment: @Hafidh; I really can't understand the language you used in the question (no offense), and that is why I can't say do this or that. However I mean If I were you, I was going to try a way to eager load all data required before I start any loop related to them.

Comment: I am fighting to understand.

Comment: @Haidh, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your query..

> SELECT tkursi.*,CASE WHEN q.no_tkursi IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE
>   1 END AS is_orderer FROM tkursi  LEFT JOIN (select no_tkursi FROM
>   tpesanantiket 
>       LEFT join tpenjadwalantiket ON tpenjadwalantiket.id_perjalanan=tpesanantiket.id_perjalanan
>       LEFT JOIN tbus ON tbus.id_bus=tpenjadwalantiket.id_bus 
>       WHERE tbus.id_bus='$Bus' AND tpesanantiket.id_perjalanan='$Trip') AS q ON q.no_tkursi = tkursi.no_tkursi ORDER BY tkursi.no_tkursi

and you've a unique query.

this query could better. without subquerys. but i dont know your db structure.

your result should be...

no_kursi | .... | is_orderer

1     | .... | 0

....

5     | .... | 1

6     | .... | 1

7     | .... | 0

Comment: Thanks, just change no_kursi not no_tkursi. Very usefull, sometimes I forgot ever use own variable/column created.

Comment: I am happy to have helped. :)